# How to secure (TLS) a grpc-js client?

Tags: grpc-js

I want to communicate via TLS using grpc-js but I don't know how to configure the lib.

I have tried to call my endpoint but it gives med error code 14 as opposed to error code 16 when I call my endpoint using PostMan. Can you help me?

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698)

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The second required argument of the `Client` and `Channel` constructors is a credentials object. A secure credentials object can be created by calling `grpc.credentials.createSsl`. If called with no arguments, the resulting channel will accept certificates signed by the standard certificate authorities. For more advanced usage, see the [API documentation](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/node/grpc.credentials.html#.createSsl__anchor).